# How to access parent component class in child component

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am trying to style parent component class in child component using css . How to access parent class in the child component in angular 2

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help you troubleshoot or help you in the codes you provide.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how/where to post questions.

Comment: suppose you have a dav with class of 'selected' and a p tag inside the dav and you want to access parent of the p which the dav and set the background color of it to yellow. 

$( "p" ).parent( ".selected" ).css( "background", "yellow" );

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you import the class for the parent component and pass it into the constructor of the child components class you can access the parent from the child.

Mind you if you're trying to do conditional styling of the parent based on the child you may want to look at EventEmitters and Outputs (see this http://learnangular2.com/outputs )

Answer (score 0):

You can get closest classof your child element any class and reach to your required parent element/class

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {        
}

ngAfterViewInit{
     let parentElement=this.el.nativeElement.closest(".yourparentClassName")[0];
     console.log(parentElement);
     if(parentElement.length>0)
     {
         //apply your style here
         parentElement.style.width=200;
     }
}
```

**Note:** closest may not work for IE and Firefox, so you have to write logic in function where it return you closest element.